# Authorization against REST API throws an error: 401 (No credentials found the request.)

Tags: javascript, rest, cors, fetch-api, alm

I want to authorize against the HP Alm Rest API, I think this "should" work, but it does not:

```
function performSignIn(){

let headers = new Headers();

headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + base64.encode(username + ":" + password));

fetch(sign_in, {mode: 'no-cors', method:'POST', headers: headers})
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => console.log(json))
  .catch(error => console.log('Authorization failed : ' + error.message));
}
```

I get a bit weird error message:

**401 (No credentials found the request.)**

This is an example from the HP documentation, done with XMLHttpRequest:
http://alm-help.saas.hpe.com/de/12.53/api_refs/REST/webframe.htm#signin-out_example.htm

Any idea? I don't see what's wrong.

Thank's a lot!

Best regards,
Daniel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fetch(…)` by default doesn’t send credentials. You need to [explicitly specify they should be sent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Sending_a_request_with_credentials_included):

```
fetch(sign_in, {credentials: 'include' , method:'POST', headers: headers})
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => console.log(json))
  .catch(error => console.log('Authorization failed : ' + error.message));
}
```

Also, incidentally, you definitely don’t want to specify `mode: 'no-cors'`. The effect that has is to tell the browser, *Block my frontend JavaScript from accessing the response from this request.*

Answer (score -1):

Thank you, that seems to work! But regarding 'no-cors', I get this error message:

Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 501. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I thought 'no-cors' will help, but actually it does not.

Comment: Cheers—you should open another question for this rather than posting it an answer. But to let you know for now: That 501 indicates a failure on the server side, right? So start by looking at your server-side logs to figure out what’s failing on the server side, and why. But anyway, for error responses, many or most web servers will not send the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header—instead they’ll only send it for success responses. So the lack of that Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header in that 501 response doesn’t indicate a server CORS config error. The real problem is the 501 itself.